# Why the select tag cannot pass the value to req.query?

Tags: javascript, html, express, handlebars.js

I am new to learning JS, Express and mongoDB.

I had some data and I want to sort them. However, I can't do it. I do console.log(req.query.sort) and it show the variable of sort is undefined, and the req.query is empty. Where is the problem I did't see?  The code is as following.

index.handlebars

```
 <div class="input-group">
   <form action="/" method="GET" id="sort-form">
     <select class="form-select text-center" name="sort" id="sort" onchange="sort-form.submit()">
       <option value="a-z"{{#if sort.a-z}}selected{{/if}}>A->Z</option>
       <option value="z-a"{{#if sort.z-a}}selected{{/if}}>Z->A</option>
       <option value="category" {{#if sort.category}}selected{{/if}}>類別</option>
       <option value="location" {{#if sort.location}}selected{{/if}}>地址</option>
     </select>
   </form>
 </div>
```

app.js

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  const sortValue = req.query.sort;
  console.log(sortValue);
 
  const sortOption = {
    "a-z": { name: "asc" },
    "z-a": { name: "desc" },
    category: { category: "asc" },
    location: { location: "asc" },
  };

  const sort = sortValue ? { [sortValue]: true } : { "a-z": true };

  Restaurant.find()
    .lean()
    .sort(sortOption[sortValue])
    .then((restaurantList) => res.render("index", { restaurantList, sort }))
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
});
```

I already tried to use the `<button type="submit">` but it also didn't work and show the same problem. So, I want to get the value from the  tag.

If use the  to write the function, how to get the value?

Comment: Unrelated to your question: I am surprised that `onchange="sort-form.submit()"` works, I thought the hyphen would be mis-interpreted as a minus.

Comment: >"I already tried to use the `<button type="submit">` ..."        
- You indeed need to submit the form, the default `type` attribute of a button inside a form is: `submit`. 
Then, I don't see your frontend JS file? You have to add event listener using `addEventListener` method on the `form` element and pass it a `'submit'` event (*first argument*) and inside the callback function (*second argument*) use the Fetch API like: ``fetch(`/?sort={data}`)...`` where `data` is a variable equal to the value of your `option` element.

Comment: @Aleksandar Thank you for your help. It can work because I make a stupid mistake. I write another <form> to wrap this <form> so that it  render twice.